# Why is dotenv returning port as undefined when referencing through dotenv?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Yesterday, I had dotenv installed and referenced, and the Server was calling on port 4000 through env, I had Postman working and referencing the server but that stopped when I started my coding today, I have no idea what I changed, because I didn't think I had done anything.

My .env file is below:

```
PORT = 4000
NODE_ENV = DEVELOPMENT

DB_URI = mongodb+srv://<xxx>:<xxx>@products.<xxx>.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
```

My `server.js` file is below:

```
const app = require ('./app');
const connectDatabase = require('./config/database');
const dotenv = require ('dotenv')
//I'm switching between these two PORT constants to debug
const PORT = process.env.PORT
const PORT = 4000
const URI = process.env.URI
// environment variable setup (tutorial runs server through the root, hence the backend/...).
dotenv.config({ path: 'backend/config/config.env'});
// DB connection
connectDatabase();
app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Server running on PORT: ${PORT} as a ${process.env.NODE_ENV} project`);
});
```

When I run with the port number called directly through server.js the port loads as 4000:

[image: Server SS]

But when I run through the environment variables I get undefined:

[image: Environment SS]

Not that it matters, but I turned off my VPN and restarted it. Not sure why it makes the error now.

Comment: Where is the `.env` file located?

Comment: There's no `process.env.PORT` before `dotenv.config()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your server.js file, you are defining the PORT const using the process.env.PORT before calling dotenv.config(), because of that you env vars are not defined yet.

Try change your code to:

```
dotenv.config({ path: 'backend/config/config.env'});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const URI = process.env.URI;
```

Comment: you can even remove one more line from  const dotenv = require ('dotenv') and update : require('dotenv').config({ path: 'backend/config/config.env'});  all in one line.